# added date filter to one of the views shows ajax error:length undefined

Tags: ajax, datetime, views

I have added a [date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module to my site and used date filter in views i.e. to search news content through date. This filter works fine in preview section, but in main page it shows Ajax error as length undefined.